# Setup JSP with SpringMVC + Embedded Jetty + Gradle

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, gradle, embedded-jetty

I've been trying for a while and I really can't wrap my head around running SpringMVC (Annotation-based MVC configuration) project with embedded jetty while managing dependencies with gradle.

I managed to display jsp page, but jsp tags are not parsed? executed?
My setup looks like this:
build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources', 'webapp']
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:1.2'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.2.10.v20150310'
}
```

My view resolver is configured like this:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setPrefix("/pages/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}
```

And I am trying to display this jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="test" scope="session" value="test"/>
<c:out value="${test}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

@Edit:
AppInitializer for setting up Jetty and SpringMVC:

```
public class AppInitializer {
    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "pl.com.imralav.springmvc.config";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/*";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PROFILE = "dev";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AppInitializer().startJetty(getPortFromArgs(args));
    }

    private static int getPortFromArgs(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            }
        }
        return DEFAULT_PORT;
    }

    private void startJetty(int port) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(port);
        server.setHandler(getServletContextHandler(getContext()));
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler     getServletContextHandler(WebApplicationContext context) throws     IOException {
        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
        contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
        contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
        contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new     DispatcherServlet(context)), MAPPING_URL);
        contextHandler.addEventListener(new     ContextLoaderListener(context));
        contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("WEB-INF").getURI().toString());
        return contextHandler;
    }

    private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles(DEFAULT_PROFILE);
        return context;
    }
}
```

Not sure what I could be missing? When deploying SpringMVC as war to tomcat the servlet-api dependency was other than 'compile' (something like targetCompile or similar), but it's embedded jetty now, so I believe compile is alright this time.

Comment: The problem is probably that Embedded Jetty does not work with JSP. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: My god, seriously? And I wasted so much time ;p

Comment: @geoand - embedded jetty works with jsp - see example project at https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a stupid problem. <s>Jetty just doesn't support jsp.</s> Jetty doesn't have OOTB support for JSP. As soon as I plugged in Thymeleaf all worked perfectly. Big kudos to @geoand and @Joakim

Comment: This is an incorrect assumption.  Embedded Jetty supports JSP.  It always has.  There have never been a time where Embedded Jetty didn't support JSP.  This is because the setup for JSP is identical in the distribution as it is in embedded Jetty.  As the distribution is itself using Embedded Jetty to startup.